# Listview becomes empty after first call

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` which is getting `JSON` data from server. When user see the listview for the first time, it's ok. But when he press back and come to the activity to see the listview again, the listview do not display any items. What can I do? I've used `SimpleAdapter`.
(If code is needed, please ask me.)

Comment: are you re-starting activity on back button ?

Comment: One option is not to finish the activity containing `ListView` while navigating away from it. But restarting the activity should work.

Comment: Please share the code. Are you populating the listview in the `onCreate()` method. If so, move that code to the `onResume()` method.

Comment: have u applied any launch mode to the activity excluding standard.